# New to MacOS and Xcode; Strange errors in Xcode while running. Worked just fine in Eclipse

Tags: c++, xcode, eclipse

UPDATE: I could solve the problem. Question can be closed! (If you wonder how: check solution)

I got a little problem. I recently decided to buy a Macbook Air since we have to work with POSIX based functions such as pthread_create, fork etc (parallel programming). It's my first laptop with MacOS on it.

I installed Xcode on it and started a new c++ project. I then wrote my program and tried to run it. There were no errors and the build succeeded but when i tried to run it i got SIGABRT errors at the strangest places. I didn't know why that happened so i copied the code in an eclipse project on my windows desktop and it worked just fine. Can you help me with this? What could be the issue? Did I maybe forget to install something?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdlib>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    const char* sequenceFile=argv[1];
    const char* patternFile=argv[2];
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open(sequenceFile,std::ifstream::in);
    std::vector<std::string> k;
    std::string line;
    if(file.is_open()){
        while(std::getline(file,line)){
            k.push_back(line);
        }
    }
    int lengseq=atoi(k.at(0).c_str()); //for example SIGABRT here
    std::string sequence = k.at(1);
    file.close();
    file.open(patternFile,std::ifstream::in);
    k.clear();
    if(file.is_open()){
        while(std::getline(file,line)){
            k.push_back(line);
        }
    }
    std::map<std::string,int> patterns;
    for(unsigned i=1;i<k.size()-1;){
        patterns[k.at(i+1)]=atoi(k.at(i).c_str());
        i+=2;
    }
    //serial
    bool seqCheck = false;
    typedef std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int> > my_vector;
    my_vector patternOccurences;
    typedef std::map<std::string,int>::iterator it_type;
    for(it_type iterator=patterns.begin();iterator!=patterns.end();iterator++){
        for(int i = 1;i<lengseq;i++){
            if(i+iterator->second-1<=lengseq){
                for(int j=0;j<iterator->second;j++){
                    if(sequence.at(j+i-1)==iterator->first.at(j)){
                        seqCheck=true;
                    }
                    else{
                        seqCheck=false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(seqCheck==true){
                    patternOccurences.push_back(std::make_pair(iterator->first,i));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for(unsigned i =0;i<patternOccurences.size();i++){
        std::cout<<"Pattern: "<<patternOccurences.at(i).first<<" at index "<<patternOccurences.at(i).second-1<<std::endl;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

That was the code i was using. I'm sorry for the mess in the code. And in case you're wondering I did indeed set the command line arguments so that's not the issue.

EDIT: It seems like the files the files cant be opened. I added:

```
else{
        std::cerr<<"Couldn't open file!";
        return 0;
    }
```

after if(file.is_open()) and it jumps straight in there. I set the filename (command line arguments with project->scheme->edit scheme and then added as arguments and i have the textfiles in the project directory. What could be the issue?

SOLUTION: The problem was that i had to type the entire path to the textfiles. I was used to have the textfiles in the project directory and then i didnt have to type the path while i was working with eclipse on my windows desktop (probably because of the workspace). Thanks to all who helped. Ill remember to type the path from now on when I'm working with Xcode. ;)

Thank you in advance and I hope you can help me.
Kazoooie

Comment: Please paste the exact error aswell, did you try to run it into debug mode?

Comment: Chances are your code invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: "Maybe the vector doesn't get filled". May I suggest you find out this first?

Comment: i posted the exception it throws.  
""Maybe the vector doesn't get filled". May I suggest you find out this first?"... i tried moving the textfiles since i wasnt sure if i have to place them somewhere else but that didnt help. On eclipse the vector gets filled(and i get the output i want) with the EXACT same code which is what appears strange to me.

Comment: Did you try running it in the debugger and seeing where it's throwing the exception?

Comment: I bet you have a problem with the working directory so the file isn't opened.

Comment: yes as mentioned in the code as comment it appears at lengseq initialisation. when i set lengseq to 27 insead of atoi(...) it throws an exception at the next line (initialization of sequence at k.at(1)) so it really seems like i the vector has a problem

Comment: @molbdnilo that might be it probably... so it doesnt go into the if(file.is_open()) and so the vector doesnt get filled... but what problem could i have there? i have the textfiles in the project directory and i set the arguments - edited it in my question (EDIT2)